# Can't share internet from MacBook using hotspot to phone ("Internet may not be available")

Tags: network, wifi, internet, internet-sharing

I want to share internet connection from MacBook ethernet using hotspot. I have Macbook Air M1 2020 so i use usb/ethernet hub. When I start the hotspot it shows up on my phone but when I connect it says "Internet may not be available" and internet is not working on phone.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have all system updates (Ventura 13.2.1)